# My PC doesn't want to connect to the Internet Modem

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, modem

I'm holding an "ALICE CASA" modem from Telecom.
For security reasons I changed the Modem password.
I have 2 PCs, the first one with Windows 10 just asked me to reintroduce the new password.
The second PC with windows 7, when I try to connect it on Internet, I doesn't ask to reintroduce the password but says "Impossibile to connect on Alice...."
Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried ["Forgetting" the known network](http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-281.html) before reconnecting?  Also, was this machine previously connected to this Wifi?  (Before the password change)

Comment: @CheesusCrust sounds like a perfect answer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [removing the "Known" or existing network](http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-281.html):

> **Step 1:** Click `Start`->`Control Panel`, Select *Network and Internet*, and then click *Network and Sharing Center*
>   [image]
>   **Step 2:** In the task list, choose *Manage wireless networks*.
>   [image]
>   **Step 3:** In the *Network* table, please select the existing profile and click **Remove**.
>   [image]

After all that, you should be able to reconnect to your network without a problem.

Let me know if that helps!